# Is akka really a solution for a deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, akka, reactive-programming

As Described [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/guide/actors-intro.html)

> While locks seem to be the natural remedy to uphold encapsulation with multiple threads, in practice, they are inefficient and easily lead to deadlocks in any application of real-world scale.

My question simply, is akka really a solution for a deadlock.

I know as long as akka actors treat objects as completely decoupled, that code never meets a deadlock scenario. But, in the imperative programming also we can simply decouple them and lock separately without keeping a lock inside another lock, so that won't be a deadlock scenario at all in traditional programming paradigm also. what's the real use case of this statement? Do we find any use case, which can cause deadlock scenario in traditional programming but prevent using akka actor model?

P.S I am very new to akka but, I can understand the call stack, shared memory and threading issues in traditional programming is very costly in the modern computer architecture and akka is a good solution in performance-wise. But curious to know this special statement also.

Comment: In brief, a thread that runs into a lock will block until it can acquire the lock. That means that you need lots of threads which can be quite expensive. Using Akka, it's comparatively easy to build software without locks at all (Akka itself uses almost no locks itself). That means you can write massively parallel software using a very limited set of threads.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of deadlocks itself, though. While you are probably correct that you can transform traditional code that uses lock into a form that is less prone to deadlocks it still needs some work and attention to get it done. Trivial deadlocks are often caused by keeping an excessive amount of locks for an excessive time. These kinds of trivial deadlocks usually don't happen with Akka.

Comment: On the other hand there are other kinds of deadlocks not related to locks but to two processes both waiting on each other to make the next turn. These kinds of locks can still happen with Akka. They tend to use less resources, though.

Comment: @jrudolph yes as I said I understand that part of the story. but when I try to understand the real world dead lock scenario like process A(a processing actor) waits for actor-A(a resource node) to finish and Actor-A waits for process B(processing node) to finish which is waiting for Actor-B(another resource node) to finish but second resource node still be depending on process A right? that deadlock scenarios cannot be avoided clearly. That's what I wanted to clarify. But yes deadlock happening possibility is much more lower than the traditional java locks.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the Summary of the Discussion in the question thread as the answer.

Basically, Akka doesn't use locks doesn't mean that Akka can prevent deadlocks from real-world deadlock possible scenarios. But, since we think each and every actor as fully decoupled and completely different architecture from multithreaded applications, it performs faster. So,

it's very less probable for a deadlock to happen!